# Consistent Label Sizing using Data Driven Pages

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, data-driven-pages

Imagine a shapefile of the 50 states in the US.
Now imagine I put labels on each one of them (CA for california, AZ for arizona etc.)
Now imagine I turn on data driven pages so it cycles through each state as its own page

How do I make it so ArcMap labels each state in the same size font?

Currently, states with a smaller surface area has larger labels and states with a larger surface area has smaller labels.

Comment: Are these label or annotation ? did you set an reference scale ?

Comment: Converting the labels to annotations will work as desired. https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-text/converting-labels-to-annotation.htm

Comment: Have you set a reference scale on the layer?

Comment: That sounds like a reference scale was set. Labels do not scale otherwise. Or you are using annotation. Also, you could put the name in the title of each page.